# Android if-else statement not functioning correctly

Tags: android, if-statement

The purpose of this app is the take a editText that would be an acronym and show what it means. (e.g. lol is laugh out loud) the problem is no matter what i input it always returns the else statement of "none found" program compiles fine. Thanks for your help!!

```
// Define Variables
EditText et1;
TextView tv1;
Button button;
String acronym;
String lol,omg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    acronym=et1.getText().toString().toLowerCase();


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        if (acronym.equals(lol)) {
            tv1.setText("lol means laugh out loud");
        } else if(acronym.equals(omg)) {
            tv1.setText("omg means oh my god");
        } else {
            tv1.setText("none found.");
        }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Seems you forgot add " " to lol and omg

Comment: acronym.equals("lol") .....

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1008278

Comment: am really lol, all question & answers have `-1`, who is doing that?

Comment: You have to assign values to variables lol and omg. If you don't it is considered empty so it is not working fine. when you write acronym.equals(lol) it looks for the value assigned to lol which in case i nothing i.e. lol is empty. So assign values to variables lol & omg.

Comment: -1 for all the answers why????

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
 Just put this line in to onclick events 

    acronym=et1.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

    like : 

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            acronym=et1.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
           if (acronym.equals("lol")) {
        tv1.setText("lol means laugh out loud");
    } else if(acronym.equals("omg")) {
        tv1.setText("omg means oh my god");
    } else {
        tv1.setText("none found.");
    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: this fixed it. but why did moving it make a difference? just want to understand.